# Eclipse class not found suddenly

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse suddenly won't run any code anymore. Here is the error message for anything I try to run:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sa0

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sa0
```

It says that the class doesn't exist, when it does. Did I delete something by accident? How do I fix this?

Comment: Is the class also named "sa"? If not then just your run configuration are messed up and the main class is not specified correctly.

Comment: very hard for us to know if *you* did delete something. `ClassNotFoundException` mostly means that java could not find the `.class` file in the directories it searched for it (classpath) e.g. because project was not compiled (wrong setings, errors, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your project's build path or carefully read the stack trace of the error. Also worth checking on your project's libraries if you are using one. `ClassNotFoundException` has also been an issue on some versions of eclipse and googling that might help.